# Swig Python typemap for both in and out

Tags: python, c++, swig

Let us say that I have a custom object `MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj` and a function that returns one of these like so...

```
bool myfunc(int a, MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj &b);
```

I have found that I can create a typemap that will make `b` a return value on the left hand side in Python by putting this in my .i file...

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) ML::Processing::MyObj& {
    // Create a persistent object to hold the result;
    $1 = new ML::Processing::MyObj;
}
%typemap(argout) ML::Processing::MyObj& (PyObject* tmp) {
    // Store the persistent object in a PyObject* that will be destroyed
    // when it goes out of scope.
    tmp = SWIG_NewPointerObj($1, $1_descriptor, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, tmp);
}
```

This way, in Python I can do the following...

```
ok,b = mylib.myfunc(1)
```

So far, everything is hunky dory.  But now let's say that I have another function that is similar but takes a `MyObj` as an input like so...

```
bool myfunc2(int a, const MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj &b)
```

When I try to call this in Python (as shown below) I get a `Wrong number or type of arguments` error

```
ok,b = mylib.myfunc(1) # this works correctly
ok = mylib.myfunc2(1,b) # this complains
```

I think it has something to do with `typemap(in,numinputs=0)` in the .i file...it's like every time it sees a  `MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj &` it now thinks it is a return argument instead of an input.

So, my question is, is there a way to handle this situation such that I can have both an input typemap and an output typemap?  Thanks in advance to all you swig-fu masters!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything at all in terms of typemaps for const reference inputs - the default SWIG supplied typemaps "just work" for almost all normal cases.

Comment: Yes indeed....if I **just** have myfunc2 then no typemap is needed and it just works.  If I **just** have myfunc1 and the typemap it works as well.  But my issue is that I have **BOTH** myfunc1 (which has a MyObj return argument) and myfunc2 (which takes a MyObj as input)....and so the typemap required for myfunc1 I think fools swig into thinking that the MyObj in myfunc2 is a return argument instead of an input.